# XSLT 2 tokenize

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm not sure how to use tokenize() function properly is such case:

**Input**:

```
<RQ>
    <Node1>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>PE</Node3>
            <Node4>some value</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VA|PE</Node3>
            <Node4>some value</Node4>
        </Node2>
    </Node1>
</RQ>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<RQ>
    <Node1>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value</Node4>
        </Node2>
    </Node1>
</RQ>
```

**Explanation:**
I want to tokenize Node3 values and copy to the output only those Node2 elements which has Node3 value equal to 'VA'. In the above example Node3 with tokenized value 'PE' should be ommited.

With the following transform:

```
<xsl:template match="/RQ/Node1/Node2/Node3">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\|')">
        <xsl:if test="current()='VA'">
            <xsl:element name="Node3">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I can get output like this:

```
<RQ>
  <Node1>
    <Node2>
      <Node3>VA</Node3>
      <Node4>some value</Node4>
    </Node2>
    <Node2>
      <Node4>some value</Node4>
    </Node2>
    <Node2>
      <Node3>VA</Node3>
      <Node4>some value</Node4>
    </Node2>
  </Node1>
</RQ>
```

The thing is I don't want the middle Node2 at all if it doesn't contain Node3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with an identity template, which copies everything from the input to the output unchanged *except* where overridden by a more specific template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now we add a couple of more specific templates, first one to completely ignore any `Node2` whose `Node3` value *doesn't* contain `VA`:

```
<!-- this works because tokenize gives you a sequence of strings, and an =
     comparison between a sequence and a string is true if _any_ of the items
     in the sequence match the value, thus not(seq = 'val') is true if _none_
     of them match -->
<xsl:template match="Node2[not(tokenize(Node3, '\|') = 'VA')]" />
```

and finally, since you now know that *only* the `Node2` elements that have a VA are going to be processed at all, it's safe to hard code all `Node3` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="Node3">
  <xsl:copy>VA</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

More generally, if you have a list of codes you're interested in (here I put it in a variable but it could be in an external XML file):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <!-- interesting codes given inline, you could instead say
       <xsl:variable name="interestingCodes" select="doc('codes.xml')" />
  -->
  <xsl:variable name="interestingCodes">
    <codes>
      <code>VA</code>
      <code>VB</code>
    </codes>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore Node2 elements that don't contain at least one of the codes
       we are interested in -->
  <xsl:template match="Node2[not(tokenize(Node3, '\|') =
                                 $interestingCodes/codes/code)]" />

  <xsl:template match="Node3">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- filter the codes in this Node3 to just the interesting ones -->
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '\|')[. = $interestingCodes/codes/code]"
                    separator="|" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the following input:

```
<RQ>
    <Node1>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 1</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VB|PE|VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 2</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VB|PE</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 3</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>PE</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 4</Node4>
        </Node2>
    </Node1>
</RQ>
```

this stylesheet produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RQ>
    <Node1>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 1</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VB|VA</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 2</Node4>
        </Node2>
        <Node2>
            <Node3>VB</Node3>
            <Node4>some value 3</Node4>
        </Node2>

    </Node1>
</RQ>
```

Comment: Nice solution. What if I wanted to process not only VA, but also VB, VC and so you could't hardcode it in the last template?

Comment: @pempek I've added an example of how you could handle a list of "interesting" codes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the above input and output the following xslt should produce the desired results using the original template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/RQ/Node1/Node2[Node3='PE']" />
    <xsl:template match="/RQ/Node1/Node2/Node3">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\|')">
            <xsl:if test="current()='VA'">
                <xsl:element name="Node3">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template (identity template) copies all the content into output.

The second template removes the `Node2` when value of `Node3` equals `PE`

The third template uses the original code, which tokenizes the value based on `|` and creates a copy of `current()`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to tokenize. This solution uses `contains` to check whether a Node3 element contains "VA".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RQ|Node1">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Node2">
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains(Node3,'VA')">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Node3[contains(.,'VA')]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:text>VA</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Node4[contains(preceding-sibling::Node3,'VA')]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>            

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the **output** you get with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RQ>
 <Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node3>VA</Node3>
        <Node4>some value</Node4>
    </Node2>

    <Node2>
        <Node3>VA</Node3>
        <Node4>some value</Node4>
    </Node2>
 </Node1>
</RQ>
```